# My ADATA superior SH93 not working needing to format

Tags: windows

HI my adata hard drive is not working for some reason it was working just fine until now it keeps asking to format but all my valuable stuff is on there just wondering if there is a fix without loosing my stuff

Comment: I have the same problem. try chkdsk /r

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using some version of Windows.

Try a different USB Port, I have had this happen with portable drives.  Sometimes a 
reboot is necessary.  **Do NOT reformat your drive**, or getting your information back will be quite a bit harder.
Also try a USB port *on a different computer*.  I have "fixed" a few problems like this just by visiting another computer and plugging in the drive, finding that it is OK and going back to my PC.

This frequently happens when the Partition table is corrupted because the drive was removed before it was done writing, and without using the "Safely remove Hardware" icon in the taskbar.

If another usb port doesn't work, you will need to recover the partition table using software. Like Partition table doctor, which is now called [Easeus Partition Recovery](http://www.easeus.com/partition-recovery/)

There is a free version, and it will allow you to:

- Recover FAT/NTFS/EXT2/EXT3 partition
- Recover accidentally deleted partition
- Recover lost partition

You can also use linux to do the same thing and use dd to backup your data prior to making changes: http://sysblogd.wordpress.com/2008/01/05/data-recovery-with-linux-from-hard-drives-cd-roms-or-dvds/

If your Drive is making clicking sounds or spinning up and then down, or you see that it is disconnecting or re-connecting after you plug it in, you may have a dead/dying hard drive.
**Don't Panic**, there may still be ways for you to get at your data.

Let us know how it goes.